# segfault with shared pointers

Tags: c++, c++11

I am using c++11 with gcc 4.8.5 and the error part in my code is like this:

```
vector<shared_ptr<My_Type>> items;
for(int i = 0; i < num_dequeued; i++) {
    auto & item = task_items[i];
    items.push_back(item->my_type_); //here item->my_type_ is declared as 'shared_ptr<My_Type>', and this is the error line
}
```

and gdb shows:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7fffc6ffd700 (LWP 9632)]
0x000000000043254c in __shared_ptr (this=0x7fffb19ed7d0) at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:779
779       __shared_ptr(const __shared_ptr&) noexcept = default;
```

I don't understand why `items.push_back(item->my_type_)` will cause the segfault error, so how to fix it?

Comment: Is item a valid pointer?

Comment: It looks very likely that `task_items[i]` is a `nullptr` (or null shared pointer)

Comment: Would you mind trying `if (item) { items.push_back(item) }` ?

Comment: Can you show more code? Like a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the issue.

Comment: Segfault doesn't always occur, so I am still debugging. Sorry if this problem is not clear

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities only:

1. Your pointer is nullptr. (`item->my_type_`)
2. num_dequed is going past the index? (`items[i]` accesses past the element but does not crash yet, crashes later)

I think these are the only possibilities looking (locally) at your code. Otherwise I am pretty sure the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: I've tested, neither item nor my_type_ is null

Comment: I would suggest you to show more context. From the context you show I cannot find out any other problem. So this would mean that the problem is somewhere else unless I missed something. @MickeyShine

Comment: I added 'if(!item->my_type_) ..' and this time gdb shows 'item->my_type_' got segfault. According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_bool , this line only check whether stored pointer is null

Comment: @MickeyShine as suggested before by myself and by Paul Rooney in the comment for the question, I think you should put a complete example so that we can help you in better conditions :)